# Bash array creation: ("$@") vs ($@)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running a script with: `./some_script arg1 arg2 "multiple words arg3" arg4`. I want to explode arguments (`$@`) into an array. This snippet works just for arguments without spaces:

```
arr=($@)
```

If I want to store the correct arguments into array I must use:

```
arr=("$@")
```

Why should I enclose `$@` in quotes?

I think this has something to do with parameter expansion and [special parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02), but I don't think I got it well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the shell, whenever a variable (including special parameters like `$@`) in referenced without double-quotes, the value goes through word splitting and wildcard expansion after it's expanded. For example:

```
$ var="FOO * BAR"
$ printf "%s\n" "$var"
FOO * BAR
$ printf "%s\n" $var
FOO
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Library
Movies
Music
Pictures
Public
BAR
```

In the second case, the variable value "FOO * BAR" got split into separate words ("FOO", "*", and "BAR"), and then the "*" was expanded into a list of matching files. This is why you almost always want to put variable references in double-quotes.

The same thing applies to `$@` -- if it's not in double-quotes, it's expanded into the list of parameters and then each one of them is subjected to that same word splitting and wildcard expansion that `$var` went through above. If it's in double-quotes, the parameter values are left unmolested.

BTW, there is another way to get the parameters: `$*`. This differs from `$@` in that it sticks all of the parameter values together with spaces between them (while `$@` maintains each parameter as a separate word). In double-quotes, `"$*"` gives a single word consisting of all parameters. Without double-quotes, `$*` sticks all the parameters together, then re-splits them (maybe at the same places, maybe not), and does wildcard expansion. Probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't surround it with quotes, `"multiple words arg3"` would be further expanded to `multiple` `words` `arg3` - ie. the quotes preserve special characters after the variable has been expanded.

In other words, when you don't surround a variable expansion with quotes, what the variable expands to will further be expanded, which would in this case eliminate the double quotes around the third argument.